# Inserting a password in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Is there a method to transform the string into a hash from mongo command line when inserting data? I want to insert account details by hand and make as many users as there is need.

Comment: From the shell? Is there some reason you cannot use another language to do that? You can write a script or program in pretty much any language you want, where drivers are available.

Comment: I can use Node.js. Thing is I don't want to create a specific page where anyone can register. @NeilLunn

Comment: So use Node.js then. What's the problem? Find a library and "crypt" ( which is different to hash ) your passwords then.

Comment: @wickerman let me understand... do you want something like: db.PasswordTest.insert({"name":"Daniele", "password": "notSecure"});
db.PasswordTest.insert({"name":"Daniele", "password": fromStringToHash("theSecretPassword")}); to be used from Mongo Shell in order to create an hash? Are you looking to specific hash algorithm or MD5 is ok for you?

Comment: Yes! MD5 is ok. I used db.CollectionName({"name" : "TestName", "email":"test@test.com",  "password": "pass"}), using "email" as login account and password as pass. @DanieleTassone

Comment: @wickerman i will wrote a reply right now.

Comment: @wickerman i just added a Answer. Please tell me if is what you want. Tnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i correctly understood your problem, you want to hash a value from the shell. I don't have understood why you need this, but i will try to give you some ways to resolve the scenario.

**Custom made solution:**

mongoDB has Stored Procedures, that you can write in JS and you can call from any context. This will give you the 100% ownership to write you Stored Procedure and call it from the shell. In this case I'm calling "fromStringToHash" function that i have previously created...

```
db.loadServerScripts();
db.PasswordTest.insert({"name":"Daniele", "password": "notSecure"});
db.PasswordTest.insert({"name":"Daniele", "password": fromStringToHash("theSecretPassword")});
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/

**MD5**

If you just need a way to compute an hash, take a look

```
db.PasswordTest.insert({"name":"Daniele", "password": hex_md5("theSecretPassword")});
```

You can also use both solutions (a Stored Procedures that internally call hex_md5 in order to be free to change that function in the future, maybe). This function is available from MongoDB shell context.